# Append to array from multiple textFields?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitextfield

I have a bunch of textFields which content I want to add to a `array`
I have tried different approaches, and I got it working with this method:

```
@IBAction func addToArrayTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if let fromTextField1 = textField1.text {
            array.append(fromTextField1)
        }
        if let fromTextField2 = textField2.text {
            array.append(fromTextField2)
        }
        if let fromTextField3 = textField3.text {
            array.append(fromTextField3)
        }
        print(array) 
}
```

Is this really the correct way to add content from a `textField` to a `array`? It feels a bit complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
let arr = [textField1,textField2,textField3].map { $0.text! }
```

Also you can create outlet collection for all textfields in IB like

```
@IBOutlet weak var allTextF:[UITextField]!
```

instead of individually hooking each one

Comment: For the sake of the OP and others that are not aware, this is a case where it is perfectly safe to force unwrap a value. It is documented that the `text` property of `UITextField` can safely be unwrapped because even if you set it to `nil`, you will get `""`.

Comment: In addition to that in other cases it's not wrong to directly use **!** when there is 100% possibility that the value will never be `nil` otherwise it's the place for `if let` or `guard`

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way:

```
    // Here you can use IBOutlet collection or form textFields array programmatically
    let textFields = [textField1, textField2, textField3] 
    let result = textFields.compactMap { $0.text }
```

And no force unwraps. Type of result is [String].